# Can't figure out println statement when value isn't found in a for each loop

Tags: java, arrays

Currently in programming fundamentals course and I'm having some trouble finalizing my code. I know it's super sloppy, but I've invested a lot of time trying to figure this out. Everything works except the final println statement. I can't get it to print out at the right time. It always prints even when the value is found. I know the problem lies in the final if statement, but I honestly can't figure out what to put in there. Thanks for any help.

```
System.out.print("\n\nPlease enter number to search for: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); 
    int search = scan.nextInt();
    int index = 1;

    for (int numb : unsortedArray) {   
        if (numb == search) 
            System.out.println("\nSearch Value: " + numb + " is found at location: " + (index) +" in the unsorted array.");
        index++;
    }

    for (int numb : sortedArray) {
        if (numb == search) 
            System.out.println("\nSearch Value: " + numb + " is found at location: " + (index -10) +" in the sorted array.");
        index++;
        }

    if (search != 1) {
    System.out.println("Search Value: " + search + " was not found.");
    }
```

Comment: `seach` is the number you'er looking for, yes?  So your final `if` basically says "If I'm searching for the number 1, then say it wasn't found".  Does that seem like a reasonable thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are checking if the `search` variable is not equal to 1, where `search` is the input you are receiving from the console from the user.

```
    if (search != 1) {
    System.out.println("Search Value: " + search + " was not found.");
    }
```

This doesn't seem quite right to me, cause it looks like you are only wanting to print this out if you were unable to find that value in both the unsorted and sorted arrays that you have.

Instead, I suggest creating a `boolean` before all of your `for` loops and set it to false... If you find the value in either of the arrays, set it to true!

Finally, change the final `if` statement to check to see if we found the value in the arrays. (i.e. if the `boolean` is true.)